# Add all rows of tableB to all rows of tableA in t-sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables and need to add all rows of table B to all rows of table A, note that the number of rows in both the tables are not static but will dynamically increase or decrease, please suggest. screen shot below to make it clear.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sR4nA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are looking for **cross join** SQL functionality along with **order by**.

```
Declare @table1 table (id int,employee nvarchar(max),Month0 nvarchar(max))
Declare @table2 table (Month0 nvarchar(max))

insert into @table1
values(1,'rick',null)

insert into @table1
values(2,'tom',null)

insert into @table1
values(3,'John',null)

insert into @table2
values('Jan')

insert into @table2
values('Feb')

insert into @table2
values('Mar')

select * from @table1

select * from @table2

select id,employee,b.Month0 from @table1 as a cross join @table2 as b order by id
```

Output Obtained: [image: Output Obtained after executing sample query]

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, the result set is all what i needed but i need table1 (in your example above) be updated with the result by eliminating all the null values, please suggest about how to achieve this.

Comment: You didn't mention anything about updating table1, or rather your question was not that clear with respect to the requirement you mentioned in the comment

Comment: please look into topics like CRUD operations in sql,JOINS,normalization in dbms,